# Facebook.authorizeCallback results with a NullPointerException when there is no network

Tags: android, facebook

I'v been trying to use Facebook SDK in my app, but suddenly the app started crashing when calling Facebook.authorizeCallback.Facebook.authorizeCallback is called in OnActivityResult() and it occurs only when there is no network.I have searched a lot but not found any solution.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should check for internet connection before calling authorize. By this way if there is no internet connection you can alert the user and stop proceeding. And there are lot of examples on how to check internet connection

Comment: In Facebook .class it says that Facebook.authorizeCallback should be called in the OnActivityResult().And my app works with out network connection.In this situation what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether there is network or not and then start the facebook process..

Checking the network availability

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) con
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        network= true;
    } else
    {
        network= false;
    }

   if(network)
  {
      //do the process for facebook
  }
  else
  {
      // show alert message network not available
   }
```